# Marker shaped canvas pen - Issues with two silmutaneous strokes

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am trying to create a marker style pencil with which one can draw on a canvas: a slightly rotated rectangle as pencil tip. My idea was to simply have to simultaneous strokes on mousedown, one of which is moved to the right and to the top a little bit so that is appears like a marker.

This is my code:

> ```
> function draw(e) {
>
> if (e.buttons !== 1) return;
> ctx.beginPath();
> ctx.lineWidth = 5;
> ctx.lineCap = 'round';
> ctx.moveTo(pos.x, pos.y);
> setPosition(e);
> ctx.lineTo(pos.x, pos.y);
> ctx.moveTo(pos.x + 2, pos.y + 2);
> setPosition(e);
> ctx.lineTo(pos.x + 2, pos.y+1);
> ctx.stroke();
>   }
> ```

When I draw slowly, it works perfectly. When I speed up the cursor, however, one of the two strokes is not ecxecuted properly:
[image]

Does someone have an idea how I can get both strokes to work?
Thank you!

Edit: Removing some redundancy produced a new issue with the line:

> ```
> function draw(e) {
>
> if (e.buttons !== 1) return;
> ctx.beginPath();
> ctx.lineWidth = 5;
> ctx.lineCap = 'round';
> ctx.moveTo(pos.x, pos.y);
> setPosition(e);
> ctx.moveTo(pos.x + 2, pos.y + 2);
> ctx.stroke();
>   }
> ```

[image]

EDIT: example:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');

  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  resize();
  var pos = { x: 0, y: 0 };
  window.addEventListener('resize', resize);
  document.addEventListener('mousemove', draw);
  document.addEventListener('mousedown', setPosition);
  document.addEventListener('mouseenter', setPosition);
  function setPosition(e) {
    pos.x = e.clientX + $(document).scrollLeft();
    pos.y = e.clientY + $(document).scrollTop();
  }
  function resize() {
    ctx.canvas.width = $('#canvas').width();
    ctx.canvas.height = $('#canvas').height();
  }
  function draw(e) {
    if (e.buttons !== 1) return;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.lineWidth = 5;
    ctx.lineCap = 'round';
    ctx.strokeStyle = '#000000';
    ctx.moveTo(pos.x, pos.y);
    setPosition(e);
    ctx.lineTo(pos.x + 2, pos.y+2);
    ctx.stroke();
  }
```

```css
#canvas {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Why do you have two `if (e.buttons !== 1) return;` in your code? there is a lot of redundancy in your code why can you just draw one line?

Comment: Oh I just realized I pressed CTRL Z a couple of times to many before I copied the code. It is updated now. The issue with the dots next to the line remains though.

Comment: better(ish) ... why don't you draw just one line?  .... `moveTo(x, y); lineTo(x + 2, y+1);`

Comment: Thanks! That solves the initital issue only partly. The line is still shaky because the points are connected with a little offset (I updated the question with a picture).

Comment: There is going to be an offset relative to when the cursor position is snapshotted. You probably need to interpolate the pen between those two points. Can you post a runnable [mcve] as a [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) so it's easier to help? Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps this [stroke](https://codepen.io/kangax/pen/GHrlF) from Kangax's nice selection of pens [here](http://perfectionkills.com/exploring-canvas-drawing-techniques/)

Comment: exactly what i was looking for, thanks!